# How to publish an ASP.NET Core app on shared hosting which not allow to upload and create .exe file

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, shared-hosting, precompile

I am trying to host my asp.net core razor page website on windows shared hosting server.

But Service Provider does not allow to upload or create .exe or any other executable file due to security reasons.

As I have searched a lot of things on google, I found for ASP.NET there is a solution like unchecking "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" while publishing the website, so might be in that case the .exe is not generated on publishing.

But in ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio 2019, I can't find that setting.

I want something like ".exe will not generate when publishing the ASP.NET Core website."

Comment: Before moving on, ask your service provider if they support ASP.NET Core hosting (sounds like they don't).

Comment: It seems that almost all shared hosting provider don't give you permission to execute .exe files since it will be risky. You better ask your hosting provider first before you purchased their service. You may test to ask Asphostportal, I'm using their service but I'm not too sure if they permit you to execute .exe files. Or other alternatives, you can purchase VPS or dedicated server, you have full permission to execute any files.

Comment: Yes, I have asked before then they have suggested a solution for asp.net to uninstall Roslyn but when I asked for the second time then they accepted they don't have a way to do this and told me to use a dedicated server because there I can use  .exe.                           I think Microsoft should provide some way for this like in asp.net.

Comment: @AnkitJalan Yes, it seems that shared hosting won't permit you to execute .exe file. You may need to find dedicated server. Have you checked Asphostportal VPS plan? Their plan seems affordable. Or you can with Azure, maybe? But it will be more expensive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

use this setting in **application.csproj** file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```